# How to set KnowAuthorityHosts in MSAL for Golang

Tags: go, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to authenticate against our corporate Azure B2C server using the MSAL written in GO. I am using the public authentication. I am able to successful authenticate with the python version of MSAL, but I have some challenges with the GO version as the discovery does not work. The generated URL for AADInstanceDiscovery does not exists. So the authentication process fails in an early stage.

I assume that I need to set the KnownAuthorityHost property in AuthParams to prevent the system from doing the discovery, but I am not sure how to set that parameter. It seems like the property and the function WithKnownAuthorityHosts in base are not exported in public.

I must admit that I am quite new to GO.

Is there any way I can set the WithKnownAuthorityHosts from my application?